# You are now synchronized with the network.

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, synchronization

when i synchronize with the network I receive this message:

"You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli."

But monerod.exe is still synchronizing:

SYNCHRONIZATION started
2016-Oct-09 12:55:22.426086 [P2P9][216.249.85.44:55740 INC]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1148310 -> 1107265 [41045 blocks (57 days) ahead]

So can i use the wallet.exe already or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, when it says you are synchronized it just means that monerod daemon downloaded the whole 'current' blockchain... It keeps synchronizing so monerod downloads the new blocks every 2 minutes and the copy of the blockchain on your machine stays up to date...

best regards

Answer (score 5):

The reason you see that the blockchain is synchronized is because one (or more) of the nodes you are connected to say that you are up to date. Just because one node says you are does not mean that you are *actually* up to date.

Some nodes you are connected to may be running an old version of Monero, and these do not have the new elements of the blockchain stored. From their perspective, your node is fully synced (57 days ahead!). From everyone else on the current network, you still have some way to go.

You can start simplewallet/command-wallet-cli, but it will not have the information from the latest transactions. You should wait until is is completely synchronized with all of the nodes.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. When you are fully synchronized you don't see "SYNCHRONIZATION started"